# Ray cluster launch on GCP fails to due to Ray wheel not being supported

Tags: python, google-cloud-platform, ray

I am trying to launch a ray cluster on GCP with a basic configuration YAML file but its failes with error:

`ray-1.1.0.dev0-cp38-cp38-manylinux2014_x86_64.whl is not a supported wheel on this platform`

I have tried using different ray wheels but it doesn't work. I can't find similar issues.

Here is the configuration yaml file: gcp-config.yaml

```
# An unique identifier for the head node and workers of this cluster.
cluster_name: default

# The minimum number of workers nodes to launch in addition to the head
# node. This number should be >= 0.
min_workers: 2

# The maximum number of workers nodes to launch in addition to the head
# node. This takes precedence over min_workers.
max_workers: 8

# The initial number of worker nodes to launch in addition to the head
# node. When the cluster is first brought up (or when it is refreshed with a
# subsequent `ray up`) this number of nodes will be started.
initial_workers: 0

# The autoscaler will scale up the cluster to this target fraction of resource
# usage. For example, if a cluster of 10 nodes is 100% busy and
# target_utilization is 0.8, it would resize the cluster to 13. This fraction
# can be decreased to increase the aggressiveness of upscaling.
# This value must be less than 1.0 for scaling to happen.
target_utilization_fraction: 0.8

# If a node is idle for this many minutes, it will be removed.
idle_timeout_minutes: 5

# Cloud-provider specific configuration.
provider:
    type: gcp
    region: europe-west1
    availability_zone: europe-west1-b
    project_id: ray-attempt # Globally unique project id
    cache_stopped_nodes: False

# How Ray will authenticate with newly launched nodes.
auth:
    ssh_user: ubuntu
    

setup_commands:
    # Note: if you're developing Ray, you probably want to create a Docker image that
    # has your Ray repo pre-cloned. Then, you can replace the pip installs
    # below with a git checkout <your_sha> (and possibly a recompile).
    # Uncomment the following line if you want to run the nightly version of ray (as opposed to the latest)
    - pip install -U https://s3-us-west-2.amazonaws.com/ray-wheels/latest/ray-1.1.0.dev0-cp38-cp38-manylinux2014_x86_64.whl
```

Comment: Is there a reason you're installing from that URL and not just `pip install -U ray`?

Comment: Can you post the full yaml?

Answer (score 0):

You're likely trying to use a wheel built for a different version of python. You may want to temporarily add `- python --version` to your `setup_commands` list to find the version of python being used, then get the corresponding wheel [from this table.](https://docs.ray.io/en/master/installation.html#daily-releases-nightlies)